# Mozilla Firefox doesn't scroll smoothly on Ubuntu

Tags: firefox, mozilla

I have problem with Firefox on Ubuntu. When I scroll on facebook or youtube it doesn't scroll smoothly like it used to on Windows. It's hard to explain but main point is when I scroll down/up it doesnt go smoothly and it's obvious.

Comment: Post a screenshot, is your scroll bar like [this](http://i.imgur.com/UQ2QxWK.png) ?

Comment: **More information needed:** Please identify if this is screen tearing (look it up), or specific to the mouse (driver). *Confirm if this only occurs for Firefox, and (if so) what video chipset/card and driver you are using.*

Answer (score 9):

Firefox 46 brought GTK3 integration and true "pixel-perfect" scrolling for touchpads.

To enable it, you must set the `MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1` environment variable.
There are a number of ways to do this, one of them would be to add it to `/etc/environment` and then `reboot` the machine:

```
echo MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 | sudo tee -a /etc/environment
```

Comment: This made no difference for me.

Comment: Put it in ~/.bashrc or ~/.xsessionrc.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and for me, the fix was to set `gfx.webrender.all` to **true** in `about:config`. I have no idea why that fixed it or what it does.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Ubuntu LTS 20.04 and Firefox scrolling wasn't as smooth as in other apps.

I followed advice from [this link](https://gist.github.com/laineantti/9a34c60a417976fe67a59e2ff0e1ba5c) : in `about:config`, set `layers.acceleration.force-enabled` to true

*Keywords for french readers: défilement doux de firefox saccadé*

Answer (score -1):

First of all, this is basic. Unplug your mouse, and re-plug it back in, into a different USB port on your computer. This may just be a loose connection. If that doesn't solve it, keep reading.

The problem could be a certain number of things, but I've narrowed it down to 2 possibilities.

1. **Your mouse scroll wheel is having problems communicating correctly with Mozilla Firefox.**
2. **Mozilla Firefox is having other problems, like not finding drivers for your mouse, or simply not connecting to it sometimes.**

What I'd like you to do is download another web browser such as Google Chrome, and tell me if the scroll still isn't working. If so, it's a problem with your mouse/mouse drivers. If it does work on another browser, It's a problem with Mozilla. To fix the mouse drivers, just look up **('Mouse Brand Here') Mouse Drivers** and download & install them. If it's a problem with Mozilla, just uninstall Mozilla, and reinstall it. If it still doesn't work, leave a comment.

Comment: This answer is *generic* enough to be for an unskilled Windows user, and have been posted on Mozilla's old help pages. *It includes steps and practices that are NOT recommended for (Ubuntu) Linux.* **Can you please provide sources or this 'wisdom'.**